# Coefficient of restitution can be greater than one

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, collision

I was reading about collisions and the coefficient of restitution. Apparently, in cases where kinetic energy is released, its value exceeds 1. I'm curious about such cases, where collision can cause release of kinetic energy. Is Nuclear fission a suitable example?

Answer (score 4):

e (coefficient of restitution) >  1    for nuclear fission reactions.

Another good example would be of 'explosive billiard balls', which are billiard balls dipped in a certain nitro compound chemical. When two billiard balls collide, the nitro compound chemical causes an explosive reaction which makes the balls go faster than they came.

Comment: I think I'd rather avoid that game of explosive billiards!